# How to add jQuery library to Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to add a jQuery library to my Wordpress site. I watched a lot of tutorials but all of them explain how to add a single js file only. But my library has multiple js files, css, etc. How can I add the whole library? Thank you very much!

Comment: try this https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress alredy includes a copy of Jquery library. In your theme functions.php file you just simply have to load it like this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );

function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
  wp_enqueue_script( 'map-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map-script.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
}
```

Comment: But I want to add a library of an interactive world map not a general jQuery. How can I do that?

Comment: function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'map-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map-script.js', array('jquery'), '20161215', true );
}